# Why does low-speed preignition occur at low rpms?

Tags: engine, damage

Why does low-speed preignition occur at low rpms and high  load a.k.a engine lugging?

Answer (score 1):

At low RPM with an open throttle ( lugging) , there is nearly atmospheric pressure in the manifold . Then you get maximum compression in the cylinders so if the fuel octane is not high enough for that compression , you get preignition. Of course if the timing is too advanced you can  also get preignition even with good octane.

Answer (score 0):

LSPI is occurring on many late model direct injection w/turbo cars. It's pretty serious and the car companies and oil companies are working on a solution for the problem. The current theory is that the high pressure squeezes oil droplets out from the ring lands and causes them to ignite and cause detonation. See [this post](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/lspi-engine-damage/) on LSPI

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a timing fault. Suspect the auto advance and retard is faulty. The distributor is worth a look at because its easily inspected. Or if you have a timing light check it that way as well.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How does this answer the question? The OP is looking for an answer on a theoretical question. He's wondering how it occurs, not that there is any fault in the first place.